# CosmosDb query to return arrays

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following data in my Collection

```
{
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-454c-4b74472b01d8",   
    "GroupId": 1,
    "Location": "London",
    "Status": "Ok"
},
{
    "id": "d129adeb-d1bf-4a89-afe3-93e3f60589fb",   
    "GroupId": 1,
    "Location": "Liverpool",
    "Status": "Ok"
},
{
    "id": "85ecf875-0e32-40b5-823a-a2545694f9b6",   
    "GroupId": 2,
    "Location": "Manchester",
    "Status": "Nok"
}
```

I need to build a query to get all possible value by `Group` for filtering.
Let's say for `"GroupId": 1` I need result like

```
{
    "Location": [
        "London",
        "Liverpool"     
    ],
    "Status": [
        "Ok"
    ]
}
```

for `"GroupId": 2` the response:

```
{
    "Location": [
        "Manchester",
    ],
    "Status": [
        "Nok"
    ]
}
```

Could you please help my to build such query? I don't know even if it possible with CosmosDb.
I have tried so far something like this but it doesn't work

```
select  
(
    select VALUE c.Location
    FROM c
    WHERE c.GroupId = 1
    GROUP BY c.Location
) as Location,
(
    select VALUE c.Status
    FROM c
    WHERE c.GroupId = 1
    GROUP BY c.Status
) as Status
from c
WHERE c.GroupId = 1
```

and this

```
select 
[
    (SELECT VALUE [c.Location] from c)
] as Location,
[
    (SELECT VALUE [c.Status] from c)
] as Status
from c
where c.GroupId = 1
```

Please help or suggest how to solve that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this with the way your data is modeled.

With the [ARRAY expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/subquery#array-expression) you can do this in a subquery for arrays within your document. But not when the data spans documents as it is the case here.

Comment: Ohhh, could you suggest how to solve that? how to model the data? I have no idea, in plain SQL it will work. I just need data for UI dropdowns with possible values for filtering

Comment: You're essentially modeling the data in the form that you are trying to project it in your question. This is true with any NoSQL database. You should always try to model your data in the way that you use it. Given how cheap storage is, if you get it in a way that is not functional to you, ingest it then use Change Feed to copy it into another container in the shape you want.